# Duplicates on querying db for products based on filters data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I have a simple filtering on my catalog. It allows me to choose the product based on its attributes and its values. For instance we have a set of beads:

Stone bead it has a size of 12mm, round shape and material of stone.

Glass/Wooden/Plastic bead it has a size of 26mm, square shape and material of glass, wood and plastic

The problem I'm facing is duplicates when I choose glass, wood and plastic materials in the filter, since one product has it all.

One product shows three times.

Here is the code for getting products:

```
    $query = Product::whereIn('category_id', $idsOfAllCategories)->available();

$filters = Input::get('filters');

$i = 0;

if (count($filters)) {
    foreach ($filters as $attributeId => $values):
        if (@in_array($attributeId, $attributes->lists('id'))) {
            $query->join('products_attributes_values as pav'.$i, 'pav'.$i.'.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->where('pav'.$i.'.attribute_id', '=', $attr)
            ->whereIn('pav'.$i.'.value_id', $values);
            $i++;
         }
    endforeach;
}

$products = $query->byId('DESC')->paginate(48);
```

Which generates the following query:

```
select * from `products` inner join `products_attributes_values` as `pav0` on `pav0`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` where `category_id` in ('6') and `availability` = 'in_stock' and `pav0`.`attribute_id` = '2' and `pav0`.`value_id` in ('39', '93', '96') order by `id` desc limit 48 offset 0
```

How could I omit the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time imagining the tables and the actual results returned, but it seems to me more like a basic MySQL problem rather than Laravel. You can, however, add the `distinct` keyword to your Eloquent query like this:

```
Product::whereIn('category_id', $idsOfAllCategories)->distinct()->available();
```

You may have to tweak just what is selected in the query in order for it to work, but you can do that in Laravel, too:

```
Product::select('id', 'size', 'material')->whereIn('category_id', $idsOfAllCategories)->distinct()->available();
```

Comment: distinct doesn't work, fixed it by using group by products.id

Comment: @UAMoto glad to hear it! You can post your own answer if you like, then mark it as accepted so others can solve similar problems as your own.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The final query should look like:

$products = $query->byId('DESC')->groupBy('products.id')->paginate(48);